# Extract title from xml file using python

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-analysis

[image]

Extract title from xml file using python

Comment: You should write the question yourself, explaining what you have already tried and what the problem is exactly. As it is, I don't know what you want, what your data looks like and how the result should be.